# ReactJS: Pass data to component to render in two Cols

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a Component that I want to use to render data that I pass, but what I would to obtain is that these data are divided in two columns. How can I do?

At the moment my data are only in column in one row:

This is my render function:

```
export const RenderDetail = props => {
  return props.map((content, key) => {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div key={key}>
          <Row>
          <Col md="8">
            <dl className="jh-entity-details">
              <dt>
                <span id={content.id}>{content.name}</span>
              </dt>
              <dd>{content.value}</dd>
            </dl>
          </Col>
          </Row>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });
};
```

This is how i pass data and how i call it:

```
const Content = [
    {
      id: 'id',
      name: 'ID',
      value: ralm.id,
    },
    {
      id: 'realmId',
      name: 'Realm Id',
      value: realm.realmId,
    },
    {
      id: 'name',
      name: 'Name',
      value: realm.name,
    },
    {
      id: 'otherField',
      name: 'Other Field',
      value: realm.other,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      {RenderDetail(Content)}
    </div>
  );
```

EDIT:

What I would to obtain:

```
ID:                                   RealmId:
value                                 Value


Name:                                 OtherField:
value                                 value
```

Comment: What's the problem with creating two columns?

Comment: I would to create two columns in which every object in Content occupies a row. At the moment I have data that are in column, one for row

Comment: Is there any particular rule to distribute the content into the two columns? If you do not have specific constraints, one way to do it is to distribute the items based on their index in the array: if is is even they go in the left column, if it is odd they go in the right one

Comment: Not at the moment i don't have particular rule to distribute. How can I do to distribute based on their index?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is conditionally render every alternate element in the array in a new row. So the code will look something like this. I haven't tested this so you can use it as a reference to get the idea.

```
export const RenderDetail = props => {
  const contentToRender = [];
  props.forEach((currentElement, index) => {
    if(index % 2 === 0) return;

    const nextElement = props[index +1];
    contentToRender.push(
      <Row key={currentElement.id}>
        <Col md="8">
          <dl className="jh-entity-details">
            <dt>
              <span id={currentElement.id}>{currentElement.name}</span>
            </dt>
            <dd>{currentElement.value}</dd>
          </dl>
        </Col>
        {nextElement && (
          <Col md="8">
            <dl className="jh-entity-details">
              <dt>
                <span id={nextElement.id}>{nextElement.name}</span>
              </dt>
              <dd>{nextElement.value}</dd>
            </dl>
          </Col>
        )}
      </Row>
    );
  });

  return (<div className="container">{contentToRender}</div>);
};
```

Comment: Oh thank you for your help, I'm sorry if i have not explain in a better thing what i mean. I would to obtain  is a container (12/12) in which every object (so id, name and value) take 6/12.

Comment: I edited my question with a little rappresentation :)

Comment: what's this other field ? I cannot see it in the array .

Comment: It is only an example if i add other field (I edit the example of before)

Comment: Updated the answer as per your question edits.

Comment: Ok thank you, I'm trying.. it only give me error on the "continue"

Comment: oops sorry. I have fixed the issue. You can't use `continue` inside `forEach`, you should use `return` instead.